# Why does the command 'pipenv --rm' not work if the environment directory is not empty? (Windows)

Tags: python, cmd, pipenv

I created a test virtual environment using `pipenv install` to practice with my new installation of pipenv. I went to remove the virtual environment using `pipenv --rm` and it gave the following output in the cmd prompt:

```
D:\Desktop\testproject>pipenv --rm
Removing virtualenv (C:\Users\Harry\.virtualenvs\testproject-Ox2snZ7k)…
[=== ] Running...Error:  An error occurred while removing C:\Users\Harry\.virtualenvs\testproject-Ox2snZ7k!
[WinError 145] The directory is not empty: 'C:\\Users\\Harry\\.virtualenvs\\testproject-Ox2snZ7k'
```

It makes me wonder: what is the point of `--rm` if it means I have to manually remove the environment directory (e.g. testproject-Ox2snZ7k) myself?

Comment: Check with `procmon` if it encounters any errors while deleting the dir's contents. Something in it is probably open by some other process.

Comment: The error is irrelevant to `pipenv` and is purely Windows' workings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `pipenv --rm` the next morning and the virtual environment was removed without an issue. As @ivan_pozdeev commented, something in the environment was probably being used elsewhere.

I will update this answer with Procmon results if it happens again.